# Race condition when using multiprocessing BaseManager and Pool in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, race-condition, pool

could someone help me out? i spent a lot of time to debug a race condition i have encountered when using `BaseManager`, `Pool` within `multiprocessing` library.
here is the simplified code

```py
import sys, time
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, SyncManager, BaseProxy
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, Pool, Lock, get_context
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue, JoinableQueue
import queue

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class Singleton:
    '''
    Decorator class for singleton pattern.
    '''
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._cls = cls
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._instance = {}
 
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._cls not in self._instance:
            with self._lock:
                self._instance[self._cls] = self._cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return self._instance[self._cls]
    
    def getInstance(self):
        return self._instance[self._cls]


class LoggingServer(object):
    def __init__(self, address, pwd):
        self.logServerAddr = address
        self.logServerPwd = pwd
        self.msgQueue = queue.Queue()
        try:
            QueueManager.register('getQueue', callable=lambda: self.msgQueue)
            self.queueManager = QueueManager(address = self.logServerAddr, authkey = self.logServerPwd)
            self.logServer = self.queueManager.get_server()
            self.logServer.serve_forever()
        except:
            raise RuntimeError("Couldn't start the logging server!")

class LoggingProcess(object):
    def __init__(self, address, pwd):
        self.logServerAddr = address
        self.logServerPwd = pwd
        try:
            QueueManager.register('getQueue')
            self.queueManager = QueueManager(address = self.logServerAddr, authkey = self.logServerPwd)
            self.queueManager.connect()
        except:
            raise RuntimeError("Couldn't connect logging process to the logging server!")

        self.msgQueue  = self.queueManager.getQueue()
        self.process = Process(target=self.loggingProcess, name = "Logging Process", args=(), daemon = True)
        self.process.start()

    def terminate(self):
        self.msgQueue.join()
        self.process.terminate()
        
    def loggingProcess(self):
        while True:
            logObj = self.msgQueue.get()
            print(logObj)
            
@Singleton
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, address, pwd):
        self.logServerAddr = address
        self.logServerPwd = pwd
        self.queueManager = None
        self.msgQueue  = None

    def connectToLogServer(self):
        try:
            QueueManager.register('getQueue')
            self.queueManager = QueueManager(address = self.logServerAddr, authkey = self.logServerPwd)
            self.queueManager.connect()
            self.msgQueue  = self.queueManager.getQueue()
            self.ready = True
        except:
            raise RuntimeError("Couldn't connect logger to Log Server!")

    def ReadyCheck(func):
        def makeDecorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.msgQueue:
                self.connectToLogServer()
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return makeDecorator

    # Overrided function to log info
    @ReadyCheck
    def info(self, info, logfile = sys.stdout):
        self.msgQueue.put(info)

address = ('', 50000)
password = b'PASSWORD'

log = Logger(address, password)

def callback(*args):
    #print("Finished!!!")
    pass

def job(index):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    log.info(str(log.msgQueue) + ":{}".format(index))
    log.info("here {}".format(index))


    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # import multiprocessing
    # logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    # logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)
    serverProcess = Process(target = LoggingServer, name = "LoggingServerDaemon", args = ((address, password)), daemon = True)
    serverProcess.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    loggingProcess = LoggingProcess(address, password)
    log.info("Starting...")
    #pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    pool = Pool() #Using a small number of worker(like 10), no problem, but if we increase to a bigger number, say 48 in my case, this program hangs every time...

    results = [pool.apply_async(job, (i,), callback = callback) for i in range(1)]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    log.info("Done")

    #loggingProcess.terminate()
    #serverProcess.terminate()
```

`LoggerServer` class is working as a logging Server(like a proxy), which manages a shared queue. `LoggingProcess` class is a log consumer class, which fetch the logs from the shared queue(managed by `LoggingServer`). `Logger` class is a producer class, which put the logs into the shared queue. As i want to share the global logger in multiple modules in order to unify the  logs format/output places/...(something like the logging standard library), so the Logger class is not fully initialized and will be fully initialized later when using it(please see `connectToLogServer`). and i highly suspect this is root cause of program hang, but i can't go further...

the hang sub-process's(ForkPoolWorker) traceback is like the following(using `py-spy`):

```
Process 3958088: python3 Logger.py
Python v3.9.0 (/usr/bin/python3.9)

Thread 3958088 (idle): "MainThread"
    _recv (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py:384)
    _recv_bytes (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py:419)
    recv_bytes (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py:221)
    answer_challenge (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py:757)
    Client (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py:513)
    _decref (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py:861)
    __call__ (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py:224)
    _run_finalizers (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py:300)
    _exit_function (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py:334)
    _bootstrap (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py:318)
    _launch (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py:71)
    __init__ (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py:19)
    _Popen (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py:277)
    start (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py:121)
    _repopulate_pool_static (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:326)
    _repopulate_pool (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:303)
    __init__ (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:212)
    Pool (/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py:119)
    <module> (/slowfs/cn59sig01/usr/zhuoc/work/qualification-kit/reproducer/Logger.py:129)
```

it seems the refcount of the shared queue failed to be decref... I googled a lot stuffs, but none seems to be the same with this... so i bring this issue here for help. Any comments and suggestions are highly appreciated!

UPDATE:
Traceback after CTRL+C:

```
Starting...
<queue.Queue object at 0x7fbe145d6190>:0
here 0
^CProcess ForkPoolWorker-49:
Process ForkPoolWorker-34:
Process ForkPoolWorker-29:
Process LoggingServerDaemon:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/slowfs/cn59sig01/usr/zhuoc/work/qualification-kit/reproducer/Logger.py", line 134, in <module>
    pool.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 666, in join
    p.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 43, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
Traceback (most recent call last):
KeyboardInterrupt
Process Logging Process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 318, in _bootstrap
    util._exit_function()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 334, in _exit_function
    _run_finalizers(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 861, in _decref
    conn = _Client(token.address, authkey=authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 318, in _bootstrap
    util._exit_function()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 318, in _bootstrap
    util._exit_function()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 513, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 334, in _exit_function
    _run_finalizers(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 334, in _exit_function
    _run_finalizers(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 757, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 221, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 419, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 861, in _decref
    conn = _Client(token.address, authkey=authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 861, in _decref
    conn = _Client(token.address, authkey=authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 513, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 513, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 757, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 757, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 221, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 221, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 419, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 419, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/slowfs/cn59sig01/usr/zhuoc/work/qualification-kit/reproducer/Logger.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.logServer.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 183, in serve_forever
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/slowfs/cn59sig01/usr/zhuoc/work/qualification-kit/reproducer/Logger.py", line 68, in loggingProcess
    logObj = self.msgQueue.get()
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 809, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 255, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 419, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/slowfs/cn59sig01/usr/zhuoc/work/qualification-kit/reproducer/Logger.py", line 45, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("Couldn't start the logging server!")
RuntimeError: Couldn't start the logging server!
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a bug in Python, see https://bugs.python.org/issue44155